# Dataset Copy, Change, Then Save

Tags: c#, datatable

I have a Button That Duplicates Records from multiple tables.It must Read The existing datatable,copy rows from a query, change some information in the rows, then write new rows back to the same table.note: it is Not Changing rows But Creating New Rows With similar information.
The Code Bellow Is a example of what i want to achieve.It will not work because it will add new rows to the same datatable as it goes along in a loop till probably a stack overflow

```
nexusDBDataSet.Drawing_Table.Clear();
drawing_TableTableAdapter.FillByJobNumber(nexusDBDataSet.Drawing_Table, OldJobcardNumber);
//Process Line By Line
foreach (DataRow myRow in nexusDBDataSet.Drawing_Table.Rows)
{
    //Read
    string DirectoryName = myRow["DirectoryName"].ToString();
    string DrawingName = myRow["DrawingName"].ToString();
    string DateAdded = myRow["DateAdded"].ToString();
    string LastAccessedDate = myRow["LastAccessedDate"].ToString();
    string LastAccessedUserName = myRow["LastAccessedUserName"].ToString();
    string ClientName = myRow["ClientName"].ToString();
    string ContentType = myRow["ContentType"].ToString();
    string Description = myRow["Description"].ToString();

    //Add New
    DataRow DrawingDataRow = nexusDBDataSet.Drawing_Table.NewRow(); // Multi Value

    DrawingDataRow["JobNumber"] = NewJobcardNumber;
    DrawingDataRow["DirectoryName"] = DirectoryName.Replace("\\" + OldJobcardNumber + "\\", "\\" + NewJobcardNumber + "\\");
    DrawingDataRow["DrawingName"] = DrawingName;
    DrawingDataRow["DateAdded"] = DateAdded;
    DrawingDataRow["LastAccessedDate"] = LastAccessedDate;
    DrawingDataRow["LastAccessedUserName"] = LastAccessedUserName;
    DrawingDataRow["ClientName"] = ClientName;
    DrawingDataRow["ContentType"] = ContentType;
    DrawingDataRow["Description"] = Description;

    nexusDBDataSet.Drawing_Table.Rows.Add(DrawingDataRow);


}


//Updating
this.Validate();
drawing_TableBindingSource.EndEdit();
tableAdapterManager.UpdateAll(nexusDBDataSet);
RefreshData();
```

I Know their is suppose to be two loops,one for reading and one for writing, but i don't know how to temporarily save the data in some sort of datatable for later write, or how to create a temporary datatable to store the reading section from the query then write it back to the actual database, I was thinking of using a FOR loop to count the lines before the write but i don't know if that will work probably.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do not copy whole table back to database as it is not needed only insert new rows in database using query or stored procedure.Copying whole table will be a performance issue and also it doesn't make sense to copy back same data so only add new data to database.

Comment: Im not sure i understand,Im Trying to generate NEW data from the Existing Data, filtered by a Query.

Comment: And as i said i dont know how to write a temporary Datatable to store the new data, i tryed '                        DataSet myDataSet = new DataSet("Temp");
                        DataTable myDataTable = new DataTable("Temp");' but 'drawing_TableTableAdapter.FillByJobNumber()'method is not accepting it

Answer (score 0):

The Only Thing I found That works is this
But It feels like a 12 point Turn!

O well to Code Review!

```
                        //Create New Dataset
                    DataSet myDataSet = new DataSet();
                    DataTable myDataTable = myDataSet.Tables.Add("Temp");
                    myDataTable.Columns.Add("ID");
                    myDataTable.Columns.Add("JobNumber");
                    myDataTable.Columns.Add("DirectoryName");
                    myDataTable.Columns.Add("DrawingName");
                    myDataTable.Columns.Add("DateAdded");
                    myDataTable.Columns.Add("LastAccessedDate");
                    myDataTable.Columns.Add("LastAccessedUserName");
                    myDataTable.Columns.Add("ClientName");
                    myDataTable.Columns.Add("ContentType");
                    myDataTable.Columns.Add("Description");


                    //Read From Database
                    nexusDBDataSet.Drawing_Table.Clear();
                    drawing_TableTableAdapter.FillByJobNumber(nexusDBDataSet.Drawing_Table, OldJobcardNumber);
                    foreach (DataRow myRow in nexusDBDataSet.Drawing_Table.Rows)
                    {
                        //Read from database
                        string DirectoryName = myRow["DirectoryName"].ToString();
                        string DrawingName = myRow["DrawingName"].ToString();
                        string DateAdded = myRow["DateAdded"].ToString();
                        string LastAccessedDate = myRow["LastAccessedDate"].ToString();
                        string LastAccessedUserName = myRow["LastAccessedUserName"].ToString();
                        string ClientName = myRow["ClientName"].ToString();
                        string ContentType = myRow["ContentType"].ToString();
                        string Description = myRow["Description"].ToString();

                        //write to temp data table
                        DataRow DrawingDataRow = myDataTable.NewRow();
                        DrawingDataRow["JobNumber"] = NewJobcardNumber;
                        DrawingDataRow["DirectoryName"] = DirectoryName.Replace("\\" + OldJobcardNumber + "\\", "\\" + NewJobcardNumber + "\\");
                        DrawingDataRow["DrawingName"] = DrawingName;
                        DrawingDataRow["DateAdded"] = DateAdded;
                        DrawingDataRow["LastAccessedDate"] = LastAccessedDate;
                        DrawingDataRow["LastAccessedUserName"] = LastAccessedUserName;
                        DrawingDataRow["ClientName"] = ClientName;
                        DrawingDataRow["ContentType"] = ContentType;
                        DrawingDataRow["Description"] = Description;
                        myDataTable.Rows.Add(DrawingDataRow);

                    }

                    //Refresh DataBase
                    nexusDBDataSet.Drawing_Table.Clear();
                    drawing_TableTableAdapter.Fill(nexusDBDataSet.Drawing_Table);

                    foreach (DataRow myRow in myDataTable.Rows)
                    {
                        //read from temp data table
                        string JobNumber = myRow["JobNumber"].ToString();
                        string DirectoryName = myRow["DirectoryName"].ToString();
                        string DrawingName = myRow["DrawingName"].ToString();
                        string DateAdded = myRow["DateAdded"].ToString();
                        string LastAccessedDate = myRow["LastAccessedDate"].ToString();
                        string LastAccessedUserName = myRow["LastAccessedUserName"].ToString();
                        string ClientName = myRow["ClientName"].ToString();
                        string ContentType = myRow["ContentType"].ToString();
                        string Description = myRow["Description"].ToString();

                        //Write back to DataBase
                        DataRow DrawingDataRow = nexusDBDataSet.Drawing_Table.NewRow();
                        DrawingDataRow["JobNumber"] = JobNumber;
                        DrawingDataRow["DirectoryName"] = DirectoryName;
                        DrawingDataRow["DrawingName"] = DrawingName;
                        DrawingDataRow["DateAdded"] = DateAdded;
                        DrawingDataRow["LastAccessedDate"] = LastAccessedDate;
                        DrawingDataRow["LastAccessedUserName"] = LastAccessedUserName;
                        DrawingDataRow["ClientName"] = ClientName;
                        DrawingDataRow["ContentType"] = ContentType;
                        DrawingDataRow["Description"] = Description;

                        nexusDBDataSet.Drawing_Table.Rows.Add(DrawingDataRow);
                    }

                    myDataSet.Dispose();
                    //Updating
                    this.Validate();
                    drawing_TableBindingSource.EndEdit();
                    tableAdapterManager.UpdateAll(nexusDBDataSet);
                    RefreshData();
```